# Filter row based on column value not present in List Of String or not

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe

```
var input1 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (10L, "Joe Doe", 34),
        (11L, "Jane Doe", 31),
        (12L, "Alice Jones", 25)
        )).toDF("id", "name", "age")
```

I am trying to filter row which are not available in the List.
I can filter based on age and id easily -

```
input1.filter("age not in (31,56,81)").show()
```

But same is not working when I am trying to filter based on name

```
input1.filter("name not in ("joe Doe","Pappu cam","Log")").show()
```

There must be some representation of string while filtering.

I am getting exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input 'Doe' expecting {')', ',', '.', '[', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', EQ, '<=>', '<>', '!=', '<', LTE, '>', GTE, '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', 'DIV', '&', '|', '^'}(line 1, pos 16)
== SQL ==
name not in (Joe Doe,abc dej)
----------------^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like a syntax error.
try:

```
input1.filter("name not in ('joe Doe','Pappu cam','Log')").show()
```

Comment: What would be the syntax if I had the words 'joe Doe', 'Log' etc. stored in a variable of type List?

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the SQL query:

```
input1.filter(s"""name not in ("joe Doe","Pappu cam","Log")""").show()
```